# Bash Script Linux print html Tags end

Tags: linux, html, bash, shell

I have a bash script and it include 2 variables, and like to print this on html, but the problem it just work the open tag and no the ending or closing tag:

```
echo <h2>${ADMIN_STATUS}</h2>
```

So the value on "ADMIN_STATUS" it is show on H2, the the html or bash no close and show on text "`</h2>`"

I mean the bash no close the `<h2>`, the `</h2>` no are working.

any idea?

Thank you

Comment: You should be getting syntax errors from that line if you aren't quoting the argument to `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` are being treated as redirection operators. You need to quote them, which is most easily done by quoting the entire string:

```
echo "<h2>${ADMIN_STATUS}</h2>"
```

Comment: I wrote: [ printf "<h2>Testing H2</h2>" ] and show the web page on h2 "Testing H2</h2>", but no close the h2 on the web page funtion tag html

Comment: @roghax85 You say you see `Testing H2</h2>` but no closing tag. `</h2>` is the closing tag. `<h2>` is the start tag. Is it the start tag you do not see?

Comment: @that other guy, exacly, the web page dont show the start tag, just the ending tag, also the ending tag no working, cause all next text it is show on h2 too.